# How to loop for a specific key for the number of times it occurs in an array of objects

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-iot

I'm currently working on an iot project which needs to calculate the average of a 15 minute window starting from :-

```
| Blocks         | Average               |
| 00:00 - 00:15  | average of this block |
| 00:15 - 00:30  | average of this block |
| 00:30 - 00:45  | average of this block |
| 00:45 - 01:00  | average of this block |
```

and so on.I've implemented one solution. The flow goes in this manner.

> `iot core -> rules engine -> sqs queue -> lambda function (triggered by cloudwatch cron job which runs it every 15th minute of the hour)`

The lambda code I've is to count the number of distinct sites (devices) in the payload and calculate occurences for each of the site(devices) as i have to calculate average in time block fashion for multiple sites or devices
Here is my test event which i have configured for now to test the function :-

```
[
  {
    "site_name": "adodar",
    "active-power": 23.4
  },
  {
    "site_name": "adodar",
    "active-power": 10.4
  },
  {
    "site_name": "adodar",
    "active-power": 2.4
  },
  {
    "site_name": "adodar",
    "active-power": 3.4
  },
  {
    "site_name": "adodar",
    "active-power": 11.4
  },
  {
    "site_name": "adodar",
    "active-power": 0.4
  },
  {
    "site_name": "jamanvada",
    "active-power": 6.4
  },
  {
    "site_name": "jamanvada",
    "active-power": 0.5
  },
  {
    "site_name": "jamanvada",
    "active-power": 4.55
  },
  {
    "site_name": "abcd",
    "active-power": 9.08
  }
]
```

Here is my lambda code to count the number of occurence for each site:-

```
export const handler = async(event) => {
    // TODO implement
    let occurences = {};
    let arr = event;
    arr.map( data => {
      occurences[data.site_name]=(occurences[data.site_name] || 0)+1;
    });
    console.log(occurences);
};
```

Here i get the correct output as expected to count the number of records for each device or site, here is my output:-

```
 { adodar: 6, jamanvada: 3, abcd: 1 }
```

Now I want to loop for each site or device for as many times as the number of occurences and calculate the average for that.
For instance, device adaodar has 6 occurences so formula is

```
add all 6 occurences / number of occurences for each site.
```

For instance adodar has 6 instaces i want to loop over those 6 objects and calculate the average of "active-power" field.

But i'm unable to achieve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to calculate the averages by storing the `active-power` sum and count for each site:

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
  let occurences = {};
  event.forEach(data => {
    if (occurences[data.site_name] === undefined) {
      occurences[data.site_name] = {
        activePowerSum: 0.0,
        count: 0
      };
    }
    occurences[data.site_name].activePowerSum += data['active-power'];
    occurences[data.site_name].count++;
  });
  let averages = {};
  for (const key in occurences) {
    averages[key] = occurences[key].activePowerSum / occurences[key].count;
  }
  console.log(occurences, averages);
};
```

Comment: I want to calculate average for the field "active-power" for each site, for instance there are total of 100 records in the sqs queue and 50 belongs to site "a", 25 to "b" and 25 to "c" I need to calculate average for all the sites segregating each "a","b" and "c" site and calculate the average for each one of them and then store them in a db.

Answer (score 0):

I have took `occurences` and iterate through each value in array using `map` and divide the sum of values by his length:

```js
> siteValues = {}
> Object.keys(occurences).forEach(key => { siteValues[key] = array.filter(x=>x.site_name==key).map(value => value['active-power'])});
undefined
> siteValues
{
  adodar: [ 23.4, 10.4, 2.4, 3.4, 11.4, 0.4 ],
  jamanvada: [ 6.4, 0.5, 4.55 ],
  abcd: [ 9.08 ]
}
```

to get the sum of each site name i have used `reduce` and divide between array length using again `array.filter` (maybe have some extra calulation operations):

```
> Object.keys(occurences).forEach(key => { siteValues[key] = array.filter(x=>x.site_name==key).map(value => value['active-power']).reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0) / array.filter(x=>x.site_name==key).length});
undefined
> siteValues
{
  adodar: 8.566666666666665,
  jamanvada: 3.8166666666666664,
  abcd: 9.08
}
```

which is equivalent to: `{ adodar: 51.39999999999999 / 6, jamanvada: 11.45 / 3, abcd: 9.08 / 1 }`